# Modify Genesis Custom Header CSS

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I am using the Associate Theme based on the Genesis framework and I'm trying to use a background image and background colour in the header.
Genesis seems to dynamically generate the CSS for this and I get:

```
.custom-header #header {
    background: url(http://xxxxx.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

What I need is to change this to:

```
.custom-header #header {
    background: white url(http://xxxxx.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

I cannot find where to do this and un-hooking the genesis header and manually coding it in seems to defeat the object of using the framework.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, please?

Comment: Hook onto the same action that the genesis header function does and spit out `<style>body.custom-header #header { background-color: white !important; }</style>` - that should be sufficient to override the background color.

Comment: That worked! I just added your code and put it in the Genesis Simple Hooks for the genesis_header Hook. You can go ahead and add that as an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook onto the same action as the genesis header function and kick out your overriding CSS:

```
function wpse_218701_genesis_header() {
    ?>

<style>
    body.custom-header #header {
        background-color: white !important;
    }
</style>

<?php
}

add_action( 'genesis_header', 'wpse_218701_genesis_header' );
```

Comment: One line 2 of your answer is that a PHP closing tag? Not saying I know better, I don't, trying to understand why (to me) the tags look backwards compared to tutorials like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm, thanks for any help

Comment: You're right, it's a closing tag. With PHP you can "hop" back in and out of the parser using closing/opening tags (pretty much) anywhere. The alternative would be to echo the style tag in a string/[nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead.

Comment: Mind blown. Thanks.

Comment: I've just come across this issue again and found your answer to my question 3 years ago!